# Moving project (under source control) to different folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I have a project under source control (TFS)

**Physical Location**

```
C:\repositry\devRep\application\DevEnv\Test\Project1
```

**TFS location**

```
$/repositry/devRep/application/DevEnv/Test/Project1
```

All i want to move this project to one level up both physically and in TFS.

```
C:\repositry\devRep\application\DevEnv\Project1
$/repositry/devRep/application/DevEnv/Project1
```

How i can achieve this?

Kindly note i don't want to lose file change history otherwise i could have followed simple approach by removing and re-adding projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Source Control Explorer right click the Project1 folder and select *Move*. In the dialog delete the *Test/* part of the name and hit OK. If the project is included in a solution you need to remove/re-add the project in the Solution Explorer. Finally, you commit through Pending Changes.

Change history won't be lost, but TFS/VS has a limitation in how it displays history for renamed/moved folders. For a single file you can see the full history before and after the rename/move. For a folder you will only see the history back to the last rename/move, but editing the *Source location* in the top of the History window to the old name ($/repository/NameBeforeRename) will show you the changes that were done while it had that name.

Depending on your workspace mappings you might need to update these. If you mapped $/ to c:\ then you don't need to do anything, whereas if you have mapped $/repositry/devRep/application/DevEnv/Test/Project1 specifically to C:\repositry\devRep\application\DevEnv\Test\Project1 then you need to update this using the Manage Workspaces dialog.

Comment: @simbada the steps are the same. Select the folder in source explorer, which contains the .sln file, then all files in that folder will be listed in the right window, so you could right click the .sln file and select move option to move file.

Comment: @simbada Do you success moving sln file?