# Visual Studio 2017 - moved local TFS workspace folders - best/correct process to re-connect?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Had to move my directories for the local workspaces for Visual Studio. I updated the directory locations in VS, but it acted as if they were completely out of sync, and asked to get latest.

I let it do so for one project - it (re)downloaded everything, came up with a list of files to which I had local changes, listing them as conflicts.  I kept the local version of all the files, so no work was lost. But when I opened the project, those files came up as not being in source control, and it offered to let me add them. So again, I have all my work, but that's a tedious process to re-connect everything. Not to mention that I'm not sure I caught ALL the files that needed re-adding.

I've also considered copying everything to other directories, download a clean copy of the project(s), doing a compare and folding in my changes.  Still messy, but possibly safer.

Is there a far better way to do this practice that I've missed?  Perhaps as a side question, is there an easy way to list all the files in a project not in source control?

Answer (score -1):

Guess you moved/changed local TFS workspace folders in file system directly. This caused some folders/sub-folders/files **lost mapping**.

In other words, all of these folders already out of source control. That's why you need to re-add or re-connect them to TFS source control.

A right way please refer how to [move an item in TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders?view=azure-devops#move-an-item-in-tfvc):

> You can use Source Control Explorer to move one file or folder at a
>   time. You should not use Source Control Explorer to move folders or
>   files that are referenced by a Visual Studio project or solution. Move
>   these files with Solution Explorer instead and check in the move in a
>   new changeset.
>
> 1. In Source Control Explorer, select the item that you want to move,
>      open its shortcut menu, and choose Move.
> 2. In the Move dialog box, either manually type the destination for the
>      item in the To box, or choose Browse to use the Browse for Folder
>      dialog box.
> 3. Choose OK.

Move is actually a delete and re-add process. You could also take a look at this similar question here: [Moving project (under source control) to different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509336/moving-project-under-source-control-to-different-folder)

---

In your situation, a quick way to solve the conflicts should be: First back up your local files, delete your old workspace, create a totally new workspace. Get latest version from sever side to your new workspace.

Then copy your back-up files/folders which copied from old workspace folder to the new one. Windows system will judge to replace files and add new files.(It may take some time) After this, TFS system will auto detect the changes in local and will list them as new pending changes. Some new add files maybe stay in the Excluded list, manually promote them in Included list.

Finally check in all your pending changes, everything should get back on track.